# when changed ViewController, need I override dealloc method?

Tags: ios

```
_request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[_request setPostValue:emailFiled.text forKey:@"Mail"];
[_request setPostValue:accountFiled.text forKey:@"UserAccount"];//帐户
[_request setPostValue:[self md5:passwordFiled.text] forKey:@"PassWord"];//密码
[_request setTimeOutSeconds:10];
[_request setDelegate:nil];
[_request startAsynchronous];
[_request setCompletionBlock:^{}];

- (void)dealloc{
    [_request clearDelegatesAndCancel];
    [_request release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

when changed ViewController, need I override dealloc method?

Comment: If you want to cancel the request when change viewController, maybe you should override viewDidDisappear and cancel the request there. If you are sure that the `viewController` will dealloc when change, you can override dealloc and cancel the request in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ARC, I think you should implement dealloc function. In this function, you:

1. Assign delegate to nil
2. Remove observer

If you don't use ARC, you must implement dealloc function to release ivar variables.